# jQuery modal append div, then prepend to previous div

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div named `childDiv` which lives inside `parentDiv`.

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <p>Parent should be on top</p>
    <div id="childDiv">
        <p>Child</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks a button, I want `childDiv` to be appended to the modal dialog window. However, once the the user closes the modal, I want `childDiv` to go back to the `parentDiv`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myBtn").click(function () {
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
        $("#childDiv") .appendTo(".modal-body");
    });

    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#childDiv") .prependTo("parentDiv");        
        })
});
```

Please see the below fiddle. I would appreciate your help!

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plusxultra/ZrUz8/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is wrong, you are missing `#` for the ID selector:

```
$("#childDiv").prependTo("#parentDiv");
```